# Xcode subproject dependency linker error with React Native

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, react-native

This is a question that relates to the React Native framework from Facebook. I imported a ReactNativeSample project that contains a lot of subprojects of the React Native. I added a new subproject that wraps the SQLlite. 
The subproject that wraps the SQLlite refers to code in the React subproject, but when I try to build the project, I get a linker error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__RCTLogFormat", referenced from:
      -[AIBSQLite openFromFilename:callback:] in libAIBSQLite.a(AIBSQLite.o)
      -[AIBSQLite closeDatabase:callback:] in libAIBSQLite.a(AIBSQLite.o)
      -[AIBSQLite prepareStatement:sql:andParams:callback:] in libAIBSQLite.a(AIBSQLite.o)
      -[AIBSQLite stepStatement:statementId:callback:] in libAIBSQLite.a(AIBSQLite.o)
      -[AIBSQLite finalizeStatement:statementId:callback:] in libAIBSQLite.a(AIBSQLite.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My question is, there are other subprojects that refer to the RCTLogFormat function, such as the RCTText subproject, and it seems to work fine. **Why does the new subproject I added have a linker problem?**
I compared the build settings of both my subproject and the RCTText, and they both seem to look the same.